# Storage Spaces Direct and Virtualization Architecture

Tags: hyper-v, storage, windows-server-2019, storage-spaces

I'm trying to figure out the best way to architect a 2 node fail over cluster with the Hyper V role installed. I can really use some input and suggestions from others who have already been down this road.

All in, I have a 4 physical machines with Datacenter 2019 installed on each. On machine 1 and 2 I have installed 1 VM each and clustered them together as a network load balancer. This work great, no problems here.

On machines 3 and 4 I want to create a Storage Spaces Direct Fail Over Cluster. On these 2 machines I also want to virtualize many services in VM's. Sql Server, A File Server, Email Server etc.

What I am not grasping is as follows. Should I create the Storage Spaces Direct Failover cluster on the Host level or at the Hyper-V VM level? Obviously I need the data replicated across both machines should one machine go down.

I am not sure what the best approach here is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the heck do you not make S2D and Hyper-V on the SAME machines? It is fully supported to have a cluster of 4 machines, use S2D for storage and Hyper-V on the same machines - it is called hyperconverged setup. It is even documented - hyperconverged

Comment: I think it would be much easier to create S2D cluster on all 4 hosts. OP iscomplicating. On 2 nodes, of course it is possible to create S2D Failover Cluster, just do not forget about witness drive. https://techblog.ptschumi.ch/windows-server/storage-spaces-direct/deploy-storage-spaces-direct-on-two-node-cluster-with-windows-server-core/
4 nodes would be more stable, IMO. Depending on the configuration, S2D alternatives should be considered. As an example: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/resource-library/starwind-virtual-san-for-hyper-v-2-node-hyperconverged-scenario-with-windows-server-2016/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/hyperconverged/

Use all of your four servers to host S2D and run VMs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is exactly what I ended up doing. S2d is pretty amazing!

Comment: RTFM is rude....................

Comment: Yeah, lets not assume people are smart enough to read. Is that what you think? Affirmative action people not reading manuals AT ALL?

Comment: I just caught the RTFM part as @NISMO1968 pointed out. I had already implemented my solution with 4 nodes and Hyper-V failover as I had no responses. Pretty much a d*ck statement. I am new to 2sd because I just updated my servers from 2012 to 2019 Datacenter. TomTom in fact I have read the manuals, blog posts, videos etc. for several days before I implemented anything. Lot's of different opinions out there with not a lot of information on real world setups. Hopefully if you ever need help in an unfamiliar technology, people aren't going to make assumptions about your cognitive ability!

Comment: Really? how entitlesa. Note that I did not set "RTFM - I pointed to the EXACT site that MS has put up for EXACTLY this type of sertup. Obviously you did not bother to follow the link provided, it contains a crapton of tutorials etc. But well, in todays entitles world, you rather user numbers in your username and do not read anything useful.

Comment: Sorry bud, gen X here.. Not an entitled millennial. I've been writing code for over 30 years. Admin work for me is a necessary bi-product as such. I don't claim to be a guru like yourself, hence the reason I seek help from such well respected condescending purists like yourself. B.T.W. I had already read the article you refer to. MS clearly states that VM's are eligible as an S2d node.

Comment: Here is some more scripture for you @TomTom: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/storage-spaces-direct-in-vm

Comment: @th3monk3y you have a point both technically and morally: You can do Storage Spaces inside a Hyper-V VM and... Yes, TomTom is an arrogant D who assumes people owe him only because he bothers to respond with some BS statements to their valid questions.

Comment: I agree. I edited ref’d “RTFM” post to remove profanity. P.S. These are cultural differences I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You can do S2D bare metal only. Storage Spaces (Direct) are unsupported inside the VMs (except Azure, but that’s another story to tell).

Comment: Microsoft had flexed out their requirements comparably recently. You can do Storage Spaces inside a Hyper-V VMs now. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/storage-spaces-direct-in-vm